# How to pass arguments to tizen native application?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I am trying to create a tizen native application which can launch another application. I wanted to create an application in such a way that I can give application name as a parameter to the application I am going to develop.

Following are the steps I have followed to understand how to pass command line arguments to the application and how to process the arguments in application:
Added log statement to check on how many arguments are passed to my application

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    pArgs->Add(*(new String(pArgv[i])));
    AppLog("index : %d, argument : %s", i, pArgv[i]);
}
```

Launched the application using launch_app in sdb -e shell

```
launch_app $hello_world_application (without arguments).
```

It is observed that the count of the arguments that are passed to `osp_main` are 6.

Logs :

```
11-14 20:11:37.411 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3904 : 3904 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(24) > Application started, arg count : 6
11-14 20:11:37.411 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3904 : 3904 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 0, argument : /opt/apps/Xbfv5mXrHt/bin/tizenSrvAppProject2
11-14 20:11:37.421 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3904 : 3904 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 1, argument : `zaybxcwdveuftgsh`
11-14 20:11:37.421 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3904 : 3904 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 2, argument : __AUL_STARTTIME__
11-14 20:11:37.421 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3904 : 3904 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 3, argument : NAAAAAEEAAASAAAAX19BVUxfU1RBUlRUSU1FX18AEgAAADEzODQ0Mjc0OTYvNzU2OTM1AA==
11-14 20:11:37.421 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3904 : 3904 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 4, argument : __AUL_CALLER_PID__
11-14 20:11:37.421 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3904 : 3904 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 5, argument : KAAAAAEEAAATAAAAX19BVUxfQ0FMTEVSX1BJRF9fAAUAAAAzOTAzAA==
11-14 20:11:38.231 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3904 : 3904 ) : virtual bool tizenSrvAppProject2App::OnAppInitializing(Tizen::App::AppRegistry &)(50) > Timer construct status : [E_SUCCESS]
```

```
launch_app Xbfv5mXrHt.tizenSrvAppProject2 "test1"
```

It is observed that the count of the arguments that are passed to `osp_main` are 6.

```
launch_app Xbfv5mXrHt.tizenSrvAppProject2 "test1" "test2"
```

It is observed that the count of the arguments that are passed to `osp_main` are 8.

also it is observed that the last argument that is passed to the application is not taken into consideration by the application.

Logs:

```
11-14 20:14:34.241 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3926 : 3926 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(24) > Application started, arg count : 8
11-14 20:14:34.281 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3926 : 3926 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 0, argument : /opt/apps/Xbfv5mXrHt/bin/tizenSrvAppProject2
11-14 20:14:34.291 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3926 : 3926 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 1, argument : `zaybxcwdveuftgsh`
11-14 20:14:34.291 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3926 : 3926 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 2, argument : test1
11-14 20:14:34.291 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3926 : 3926 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 3, argument : HAAAAAEEAAAGAAAAdGVzdDEABgAAAHRlc3QyAA==
11-14 20:14:34.291 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3926 : 3926 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 4, argument : __AUL_STARTTIME__
11-14 20:14:34.291 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3926 : 3926 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 5, argument : MwAAAAEEAAASAAAAX19BVUxfU1RBUlRUSU1FX18AEQAAADEzODQ0Mjc2NzQvOTE0MjQA
11-14 20:14:34.291 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3926 : 3926 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 6, argument : __AUL_CALLER_PID__
11-14 20:14:34.291 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3926 : 3926 ) : int OspMain(int, char **)(30) > index : 7, argument : KAAAAAEEAAATAAAAX19BVUxfQ0FMTEVSX1BJRF9fAAUAAAAzOTI1AA==
11-14 20:14:34.681 : INFO / tizenSrvAppProject2 ( 3926 : 3926 ) : virtual bool tizenSrvAppProject2App::OnAppInitializing(Tizen::App::AppRegistry &)(50) > Timer construct status : [E_SUCCESS]
```

Kindly provide me some pointers on:

How are arguments passed to `osp_main`?

How to make use of the arguments passed to the application by the application?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I have launched phone app in tizen from my app using the following code

```
HashMap extraData;
extraData.Construct();
String typeKey = L"http://tizen.org/appcontrol/data/call/type";
String typeVal = L"voice";
extraData.Add(&typeKey, &typeVal);

AppControl* pAc = AppManager::FindAppControlN(L"tizen.phone",
L"http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/dial");
if (pAc)
{
pAc->Start(&number, null, &extraData, null);
delete pAc;
}
```

And also you need to add the privillege , Application launch

Answer (score 0):

To receive the launch argument, AppControl feature can be used.

[Delivering Launch Arguments](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/guide/app/delivering_launch_arguments.htm)

> You can supply data when launching the application control, and the
>   called application control must process this data properly. The
>   delivered data can be processed using the
>   IAppControlProviderEventListener::OnAppControlRequestReceived()
>   method.

Here is the [pointer to AppControl](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/guide/app/app_controls.htm).

For the calling part, refer to the Arju's answer.